# Download CSV not working with URL in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, export-to-csv

I am trying to download a CSV file through the root URL. But it is not working. What I trying to do is when the user enters the root URL http://localhost:3000 then a CSV is downloaded. I am not able to figure out the issue of why it is not working.

controller.rb

```
def index

 csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|

  file = JSON.parse(File.open("app/assets/javascripts/data.json").read)
    @data = file
    new_file = @data.sort_by!{ |m| m["name"] }
    new_file.each do |hash|
        hash['name'] = (hash.values[2])
        hash['city'] = (hash.values[3])
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data csv_string, type: :csv }
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
root :to => "name#index"
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1 align="center">File is downloaded</h1>
```

Comment: Where is `csv_string` defined?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh I am sorry it was a typo error. I have changed it to csv_string.

Comment: What is happening instead? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @DanielRikowski It doesn't throw any error. It just the CSV is not created

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using the *root* route, which cannot have a format parameter.

Run `rake routes` and you'll see something like this:

```
         articles GET      /articles(.:format)           
                  POST     /articles(.:format)           
      new_article GET      /articles/new(.:format)       
     edit_article GET      /articles/:id/edit(.:format)  
          article GET      /articles/:id(.:format)       
                  PATCH    /articles/:id(.:format)       
                  PUT      /articles/:id(.:format)       
                  DELETE   /articles/:id(.:format)       
             root GET      /             <------------- NO FORMAT
```

In other words the format is always `:html` and consequenctly the `format.csv` block is never executed, just the `format.html` block.

Even if there was a format parameter you'd have to use the url `http://localhost:3000/.csv` which looks really weird and probably is the reason, Rails doesn't make this possible.

Try using a regular resource route first, like this:

```rb
resources :names
```

It should work using your existing code using `http://localhost:3000/names.csv`

If it works then you can "prettify" your URL using `match` or `scope` if you really need the route to be the root route.

Like this:

```rb
get '/', to: "name#index", format: :csv
```

which is the same as:

```rb
match '/', to: "name#index", format: :csv, via: [:get]
```

Comment: this is the error I am getting after I have changed my routes to resources :names **You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"**